# Subscribing to an RxJS Observable in a decorator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am attempting to subscribe to an RxJS observable in a TypeScript decorator, in an Angular application.

Specifically, I'm attempting to create an `@OnLogin()` decorator that causes a method in a service to execute when the auth service emits from the `login$$` subject (exposed as `login$`).

Auth service:

```js
    // value doesn't matter, only that a login occurred
    private login$$ : BehaviorSubject<void>;

    get login$() : Observable<void> {
        return login$$.asObservable();
    }
```

Here is the decorator definition (not working):

```js
export function OnLogin() {

    return function(target : any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {

        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function(...args : any[]) {

            const authService : AuthService = AppModule.injector.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
            if (authService) {
                console.warn("Auth service found");
            } else {
                console.warn("No auth service found");
            }

            authService.login$
                .subscribe(() => {
                    originalMethod.apply(this, args);
                });

        }

        return descriptor;
    }
}
```

The injector is exposed as a static member of AppModule:

app.module.ts:

```js
export class AppModule {
    static injector : Injector;

    constructor(injector : Injector) {
        AppModule.injector = injector;
    }
}
```

In a service that makes use of the decorator, I want the call to look like this:

```js
@OnLogin()
doLogin() : void {
   // initialize items that need to do so on login
}
```

Unfortunately, the decorator function inside `descriptor.value` is not executing at all, nor is the decorated function. One idea I had is that I'm not preceding the call to `originalMethod.apply()`  with a return. But since that only occurs when `$login` emits, is that the correct way to manage it?